# Error when install psycopg2 on mac

Tags: django, macos, python-3.4

When i try to install psycopg2 on mac using pip install -r requirements.txt
I got error.

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
Using cached psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.1'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/r6/0rwq93rx6n59lbn8jrng11gm0000gn/T/pip-build-hat1f3jy/psycopg2/
```

I could not solve it.`python3.4.3` `mac10.12`
could anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into here is that psycopg2 isn't compatible with Postgres 10 unless you use version 2.7 or higher.

So either you will need to install an earlier version of postgres or port whichever package you are trying to install to psycopg2 2.7.x

The relevant issue that was resolved in version 2.7 can be found here
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/489